# Complex MS Access NOT IN Type Query

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to write a query that returns the literal opposite of the following query.

There are three tables. Assets, Software, SoftwareInstalls.

### ASSETS SCHEMA

ID (Auto)
Hostname (Text)

### ASSETS DATA

1,"PC1"
2,"PC2"
3,"PC3"
4,"PC4"
5,"PC5"
6,"PC6"
7,"PC7"
8,"PC8"

### SOFTWARE SCHEMA

ID (Auto)
Title (Text)

### SOFTWARE DATA

1,"Office"
2,"Project"
3,"Visio"
4,"Visual Studio"
5,"Doors"

### SOFTWAREINSTALLS SCHEMA

fkAssetID (Number)
fkSoftwareID (Number)

### SOFTWAREINSTALLS DATA

1,1
2,1
3,1
4,1
5,1
6,1
7,1
1,2
2,2
3,2
4,2
5,3
6,3
7,3
4,4
5,4

### Relationships

Assets and Software have one-to-many from ID to the respective fk in SoftwareInstalls

### Query to return all software installed on each asset:

SELECT Assets.[Hostname], Software.Title
FROM Software INNER JOIN (Assets INNER JOIN SoftwareInstalls ON Assets.ID = SoftwareInstalls.fkAssetID) ON Software.ID = SoftwareInstalls.fkSoftwareID
ORDER BY Assets.[Hostname];

### Returns:

"PC1","Project"
"PC1","Office"
"PC2","Office"
"PC2","Project"
"PC3","Project"
"PC3","Office"
"PC4","Project"
"PC4","Office"
"PC4","Visual Studio"
"PC5","Visio"
"PC5","Visual Studio"
"PC5","Office"
"PC6","Visio"
"PC6","Office"
"PC7","Visio"
"PC7","Office"

I want to design a query that returns the exact opposite data from above so we can know which assets don't have which software installed.

### Desired query data:

"PC1","Visio"
"PC1","Visual Studio"
"PC1","Doors"
"PC2","Visio"
"PC2","Visual Studio"
"PC2","Doors"
"PC3","Visio"
"PC3","Visual Studio"
"PC3","Doors"
"PC4","Visio"
"PC4","Doors"
"PC5","Project"
"PC5","Doors"
"PC6","Project"
"PC6","Doors"
"PC6","Visual Studio"
"PC7","Project"
"PC7","Doors"
"PC7","Visual Studio"
"PC8","Project"
"PC8","Visio"
"PC8","Doors"
"PC8","Visual Studio"
"PC8","Office"

In SQL, the most I can wrap my head around is a "NOT IN" subquery for a single computer with all software or a single software for all computers.

In VBA, this could be done in a few lines of code with two loops. I can't though figure out how best to incorporate this into the database as a query/view.

Thanks,

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're not going to use an `NOT IN` statement, but are going to check if it's not in SoftwareInstalls using a count.

We first do a cross join that selects every possible combination between hostname and software title, and then use a where statement that checks that the combination between hostname and software title is not in the SoftwareInstalls table (`Count` = 0, you could rewrite this as a `NOT IN` statement, but this runs fine).

```
SELECT a.Hostname, s.Title
FROM Assets a, Software s
WHERE (SELECT Count(fkAssetID) FROM SoftwareInstalls i WHERE i.fkAssetID = a.ID AND i.fkSoftwareID = s.ID) = 0
```

Comment: OMG, this is so off the rails from along the lines that I was thinking, oh, and 1000 times easier to understand/read/write/etc. Thanks for opening my eyes to a new way of looking at ways of querying!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that "IN" is the approach you want to take here. Try using a NOT EXISTS to compare your result set to another list. This example should give you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT lst.*
  FROM
        (SELECT Assets.Asset_ID, Assets.Hostname, Software.Software_ID, Software.Title
        FROM Assets, Software ) lst
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM softwareinstalls si 
                     WHERE si.Asset_id = lst.Asset_Id and si.Software_Id = lst.Software_Id)
```

Here's how the query works (I renamed all of your ID fields to match the table name).

The first subquery, lst, builds a list of all possible combinations of asset and software by cross joining the Asset and Software tables.

Next, we take that list and compare it to the list of installs, asking it to return everything that doesn't match on both Asset_Id or Software_Id.

The NOT EXISTS coudl be replaced with a LEFT JOIN and "IS NOT NULL", but I think this reads easier.

Comment: I don't really understand why the FROM statement contains a subquery. But good work, a `NOT EXISTS` might be more efficient than a `Count` =0

Comment: So this is where I was originally headed but, I was way over thinking it and to your point, didn't even consider it due to the matching ID field names.  Confirmed that this is also a valid solution.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Your query cross joins Assets and Software in the FROM clause. I just turned the cross join into a subquery because I thought it was easier to read and explain that way. I'd assume that the two would create the same execution plan..

Comment: @DataWriter I usually try to keep the queries as short as possible, but indeed, they probably execute the same (there's no real way to figure out execution plans in Access short of benchmarking and seeing execution time is the same, so we can't know)